# Do we want to reduce the number of votes needed to Close/Reopen questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close

Recently Stack Overflow reduced the number of votes needed to close/reopen questions from 5 to 3 after a successful experiment to see if it was worth it.

The results were that it did improve the rate at which bad questions were closed but didn't result in good questions being incorrectly closed.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good

Do we want to go down the same route here on Web Apps?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Agree with @Rubén, yes. I think that would be an improvement here.

Comment: indeed we should

Comment: I'll post some stats from August/September... in a bit but I just had this turned on for y'all. From looking at the last few months it's clear that it should help you out a lot and there's no need to run a second test.

Comment: @Catija Thank you