# Why was this question on setting up automatic alerts for new YouTube videos matching keywords closed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

This question was closed by a moderator as "needs details or clarity."

> [Can I setup automatic alerts for new YouTube videos that match keywords?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171660/18147)
>
> I wonder if I can set up a notification for YouTube if there is a new video that contains a specific keyword in the title or hashtags.

I added the following comment a few days ago but it was [deleted](https://web.archive.org/web/20230812051146/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171660/can-i-setup-automatic-alerts-for-new-youtube-videos-that-match-keywords) by a moderator:

> Why was question that closed? Looks perfectly fine to me. What detail is missing or what needs to be clarified? –
> Franck Dernoncourt
> Aug 12 at 5:10

So I am asking here on Meta.  Why was that question closed?

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid that’s just going to be another question out of a long list of questions that were unilaterally closed for reasons yet to be explained. (See: [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584) and its [linked meta posts](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4984?sort=active))

The "needs details or clarity" close reason should be for questions that are ambiguous, vague, or unclear about what the actual question is, but the issue stated in the question is clear and understandable. I do not see what further details or clarity are required.

> I added a comment a few days ago asking what the moderator what they thought was unclear or which details needed to be added, but my comment got deleted just after a few hours I posted it, so I am asking here on Meta.

That’s strange. I don’t think it’s appropriate to remove comments asking for *clarification* on a question that was closed as "needs details or *clarity*". Seems counter-productive.

Whenever I vote to close a question on any SE site as "needs details or clarity", I always try to leave a comment (if there is none yet) to help the asker improve their question. This way, they can know what details to add or clarify to have their question reopened or prevent it from being closed in the first place.

Closing questions without comment and deleting comments asking about the closure seems like an attempt to discourage community feedback and discussion. It seems problematic to me.